# I have upgarade from php 5 to 7 and i cant access my dtabase. why dose the code not work

Tags: php, mysql

my code dose not work when trying to connect to my database

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(@$_SESSION [auth] != "yes" )
     {
       header ("location: processlogin.inc");
     exit ();
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it. For example, the code above does not even try to make a database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a limb here, I'm going to say that it's because the mysql extension has been removed on php 7. You can still install it as a pecl extension or [choose another one](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

You can review other incompatible changes in the [migration guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php).